# Defining a variable through a subclass

Tags: java, class, variables, inheritance

I'm using Java and I'd like an attribute of a class to be of any class derived from the class `Service`. I tried to write this:

```
private ? extends Service var
```

but it didn't work. What should I write?

Comment: How did you manage to arrive at the more complicated (and invalid) syntax *first*? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you need

```
private Service var
```

`var` can be a reference to any sub-class of `Service`.

Answer (score 2):

Your class should look like this:

```
public class ClassName<T extends Service> {
...
   private T var;
...
}
```

Comment: +1 a good other option depending on need (which isn't expressed very well..)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field to be of any class derived from `Service` you simply do:

```
private Service var;
```

when you assign, you can use any class that extends `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to define a variable of type Service?

```
private Service var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just do

private Service var;

Any subclass of Service would still be a Service object right?